# matplotlib raises [WinError 10054] in visual code debugging session

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib

I'm debugging with visual code **locally** and trying to plot with matplotlib.
after executing **any** plot command, say: `plt.plot([0,1,2,3])`

This error shuts down the debug session:

```
[WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

visual code pyhton version: v2022.10.1

python version: 3.7.13

anaconda version: 4.13.0

matplotlib: 3.5.1
```

This seems to persist regardless of my local pc connection.

Does anyone know what may cause this?